# Servidor local node.js não encontra arquivo html

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

Sou iniciante no fórum (em node.js e html também) então qualquer erro avisem.

Eu queria fazer um servidor local com node.js (server.js), código abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Esse código deveria mostrar o conteúdo do seguinte código em html (index.html), código abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O problema é que na página web retorna o erro 'File not found!' (previsto no código javascript caso retornasse erro):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Os dois arquivos se encontram na mesma pasta:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Aparentemente o servidor inicia normalmente, o problema é realmente na hora de encontrar o arquivo html. Alguém saberia o porque de não estar encontrando o arquivo?

Answer (score 0):

Tenta

```
fs.readFile(__dirname+'/index.html'....
```

Comment: valeu funcionou ak